# Clicking Upgrade for LTS 22.04 not working

Tags: 22.04, lts, troubleshooting

I've been prompted everyday since the latest LTS has become available and when I click to upgrade nothing happens. I've looked online and followed guidelines for updating and upgrading my system before clicking upgrade but still no success when I click upgrade. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a Dell XPS 13 plus 9320 that came with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It's recommended to keep your factory installed release (supported until April of 2025). You can disabled the upgrade suggestion in Software & Updates.

Comment: Step 1: Open a Terminal. Run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Step 2: Run `sudo apt upgrade`. If your output has ANY errors, copy-and-paste the complete output into your question above. Stop and fix all errors before proceeding.

Comment: Step 3: Run `sudo do-release-upgrade`. If you encounter ANY errors, copy-and-paste the complete output into your question above.

Comment: I have upgraded factory installed release 20.04 to 22.04. You can try, you have the image to restore the system anyway. Simply, don't erase factory image.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer which worked for me:

Add a repository for "somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu" for focal (20.04)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:somerville-dla-team/ppa
```

Then open software updates, select settings and deactivate "somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu" for bionic (18.04).
After this I was able to upgrade my system using the upgrade button.

**Explanation:**

Running the upgrade from the command line gives this:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

This shows that it's the "dell-linux-assistant" which is being held back:

```
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
dell-linux-assistant/bionic 2.2.0545 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.0544]
dell-linux-assistant/now 2.2.0544 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.2.0545]
```

And this shows that it's the "somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu" repository:

```
sudo apt-cache policy dell-linux-assistant
dell-linux-assistant:
   Installed: 2.2.0544
   Candidate: 2.2.0545
   Version table: 2.2.0545 500
   500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```